# Select where row number = rownum

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to run this query to select a row by its row number but I keep getting  unknown column 'row' in where clause. Is this query possible

```
SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS row, pi.*
FROM ci_patient_info pi
where row = 2
```

Comment: Where do you initialize `@row` to zero?  What sense is there in numbering your result set if you don't specify an ORDER BY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in a `subquery`

```
SELECT c.*
FROM
   (
      SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS row, pi.*
      FROM ci_patient_info pi
   ) c
where c.row = 2
```

**UPDATE 1**

maybe your subquery should look like this,

```
  SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS row, pi.*
  FROM ci_patient_info pi, (SELECT @row:=0) x
```

Comment: this query is giving me an empty result set

Comment: @RaymondFeliciano, that's probably because you don't explicitly initialize `@row`, so it retained its highest value (which was greater than two) from the previous run.

Comment: is your query returns correct result if it was not on a subquery?

Answer (score 1):

If you need the second record, just use the `LIMIT` clause.

```
SELECT  pi.*
FROM ci_patient_info pi LIMIT 1, 1
```

Comment: Originally this was the way I was querying the db. The problem with this is that if I select row 35 and use the select @row statement since I only row 35 result set will have one record so therefore the row number will not be 35 but 1. Is there a way to get the corresponding row number for that record