# MYSQL use row number in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

how do I use my row number as part of my where clause?

I have, let say, 25 data and I only want to get first 10 rows or get the rows from 11 to 20.

How do I use the row number? I can't execute this query below

```
SET @row_number:=0;
SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number, col1, col2, col3
FROM table
WHERE row_number > 1 and row_number < 10;
```

**Update:** The problem is that in my where clause row_number is unknown in table
**Update 2:** Thanks guys! Anyway, I found this. [Select where row number = rownum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821709/select-where-row-number-rownum)

Comment: It says unknown column row_number..why is this? D:

Comment: because it is not a column!?

Comment: then how do i get row number? D:

Comment: Use rownum in your query while limit in selection. Something like : `SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 as row_number, col1, col2, col3 FROM table LIMIT 1, 10;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `OFFSET` and `LIMIT`

[Check this article](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/451.cfm)

So to get rows 11 to 20 you would do

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM table
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10;
```

Comment: The problem is "Unknown column row_number in where clause"

Comment: Yes sorry, I just copied and pasted your code, didn't realize all that was trying to achieve what `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` does. Check my Edit

Comment: oh god thanks! my code was a bit complex, I was trying this one stackoverflow.com/questions/12821709/select-where-row-number-rownum :D