# Unknown column 'ROWNUM' in 'where clause'

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I read a lot of topics about this problem but most of them were having problem with some complex (at least for me) code; 
I have followed the oracle [ROWNUM Pseudocolumn](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm) guide but when I write

```
SELECT * FROM " + tableName + "
WHERE ROWNUM < 12;
```

I get this error:

> Unknown column 'ROWNUM' in 'where clause'

I then tried to do like the solution suggested here [Select where row number = rownum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821709/select-where-row-number-rownum)
but nothing changes.

My code looks like this:

```
sql = "SELECT C.* "
    + "FROM ( SELECT * "
    + "       FROM " + tableName + " ) C "
    + "WHERE C.ROWNUM < 12;";
resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
```

Comment: I have a database called "cars", why does it matter? Hope my question isn't that stupid, I started learning about jdbc only 2 days ago so I am a real newbie

Comment: Rownum is for Oracle only but you tagged your question with mysql.

Comment: Use `limit 12` instead of `rownum`. `rownum` is oracle function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp.

`ROWNUM` is used in `Oracle`. Assuming you are using `MySQL` as you have tagged your question to MySQL.

You can change `ROWNUM` with `limit clause`

```
SELECT * FROM " + tableName + "
LIMIT 11;
```

Comment: You really mean 11 instead of 12, but I'm upvoting because you noted where `rownum` *is* used and got rid of the subquery.

Comment: Oh yes, its 11 instead of 12, I did not notice `<` instead of `<=`. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: After @Tim3880 and RubahMalam commented I searched and found the same link. I was just about to answer my own question saying the same thing you said and thank them but you were faster. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will helpful for ur problem:

`select * from (select * from " + tableName + ") "WHERE C.ROWNUM < 12;`

Answer (score 0):

Use the below

```
sql = ""
    + "SELECT C.*,ROWNUM as RECNUM "
    + "FROM ( "
    + "     SELECT * "
    + "     FROM " + tableName + " ) C "
    + "WHERE C.RECNUM < 12;";
```

resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);

Answer (score 0):

Try this : [if you use mysql]

```
sql = ""
        + "SELECT C.* "
        + "FROM ( "
        + "     SELECT * "
        + "     FROM " + tableName + " ) C "
        + "LIMIT 11;";
resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
```

For sql server :

```
SELECT TOP 12 ...
```

Comment: That would actually be `LIMIT 11`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I see, thought it was `rownum <= 12`

Comment: thanks for your answer but according to  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp it's not "WHERE LIMIT 12" but just "LIMIT 12". The 12 isn't important, it was there just to put a number

Comment: This works for me in mysql workbench but somehow hibernate is complaining Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: 
unexpected token: LIMIT near line 1,